# Creating free empty space between two planes in Solidworks

Tags: cad, solidworks

I have rotary encoder with RGB LED illuminated Shaft (Bourns PEL12T-4226F-S1024) and I am designing volume knob using Solidworks 2013, that will be used with this encoder. Now, I've managed to design basic shape and made extrusions, then add a hole for potentiometer shaft, that is all ok. But, between potentiometer hole upper plate and global upper plate I need empty space, so the knob will transfer illuminated colors. How do I add empty space between two planes using Solidworks? And how do I "cut" slots from chamfered surface, so the illumination can be visible?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy to do.

Click on the Cut Extrude symbol and then click on the top face on the model and select the top view and now u can see the center of the knob hole click circle and click on that and draw the circle define it and extrude it all the way.